# Add dynamic text (while the user writes) inside label

Tags: jquery

In a form Im trying to add some dynamic text, while the user writes:

```
<label for="signup_username">Username</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="signup_username" name="signup_username">
```

For example if user type "JOSOROMA" then the dynamic text inside label "signup_username" will reflect:

```
<label for="signup_username">http://www.localhost.lh/josoroma</label>   
<input type="text" value="" id="signup_username" name="signup_username">
```

If user type "obama" then then the dynamic text inside label "signup_username" will reflect:

```
<label for="signup_username">http://www.localhost.lh/obama</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="signup_username" name="signup_username"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of :

```
<label for="signup_username">http://www.localhost.lh/<span></span></label>
<input type="text" value="" id="signup_username" name="signup_username">

<script>
$('#signup_username').keyup(function(e) {
    $(this).prev('label').find('span').html($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Didn't have time to try it out:

```
$("#signup_username").keyup(function(){
    var url = "http://www.localhost.lh/",
        txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).prev().text(url+txt);
});
```